# How to use Identities for to implementing hole punching in my custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2, varnish, holepunching

I tried this link [link](https://trellis.co/blog/magento2-fpc-hole-punching/)

Not working for me.

Any other way to achieve the hole punching.

Comment: @H_Parekh.please check user question again?

Comment: @H_Parekh The link you provide is for Magento 1. The OP is asking about Magento 2

Comment: Yes, I tried in Magento 2.

Comment: You are asking about hole punching and answering about implement cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this.

Magetno 2 + Varnish = dynamic content

We can achieve hole punch without using

1. Cacheable false
2. isPrivateScope
3. Ajax

   - Check the link [Hole Punching Concepts](https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2)

In getVaryString method from Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context.

```
public function getVaryString()
{
    $data = $this->getData();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        if (!empty($this->cookieManager->getCookie('type_po')) && $this->cookieManager->getCookie('type_po') == 1) {
                array_push($data, "type", 'access_po');
        }
            ksort($data);
            return sha1(serialize($data));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Method return vary string to be used as a part of page cache identifier.

If The Page Cache Identifier already exists, the page render from varnish cache otherwise page rendering newly.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, the answer whatever you have posted is not relevant to your question. Mainly Hole punching is used to make some specific block to show non-cached information which is part of cached page.

Please be clear on your question & answer.

And you can check "***sections on magento 2***" for achieving hole-punching functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

After going crazy to find a solution for it, finally I got a working solution for Magento 2.3.2 + Varnish + GeoIP. To accomplish it you can use the `Cache Context` and `Page Variations` which are very simple to implement.

First create a Plugin into your module for `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context`.

**File: app/code/Vendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context">
        <plugin name="atwix_country_cache_context_plugin"
            type="Vendor\YourModule\Plugin\CustomerCountryCacheContextPlugin" />    
    </type>
</config>
```

Then the Plugin implementation

**File: Vendor/YourModule/Plugin/CustomerCountryCacheContextPlugin.php**

```
/**
 * Plugin on \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
 */
class CustomerCountryCacheContextPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context::getVaryString is used by Magento to retrieve unique identifier for selected context,
     * so this is a best place to declare custom context variables
     */
    function beforeGetVaryString(\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $subject)
    {
        $country = $this->yourWayToGetTheCountry();
        $defaultCountryContext = 'Brazil';
        $subject->setValue('CONTEXT_AGE', $country, $defaultCountryContext);
    }
}
```

And the last step is to add the `X-Magento-Vary` cookie to transfer context on the HTTP layer in your Varnish.

```
sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    ... more ...
}
```

For more info visit:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/cache-context-and-page-variations-in-magento-2/