# Magento 2 - Page cache with hole punch

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, blocks, full-page-cache, holepunching

Magento `page cache` cached some of the `blocks` that has dynamic value, like Wishlist count on `header` for `logged in customers`

I can make it dynamic using **Ajax**, but then it came to my knowledge that it could also be done using **Hole punch**. (***Not `cacheable="false"`***)

My question is, how can I set `hole punch` for `wishlist count` on `header`? I need a path where I can do some research on this

I have checked this post, but it has no a satisfactory answer:
[How to use Identities for to implementing hole punching in my custom module magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229430/how-to-use-identities-for-to-implementing-hole-punching-in-my-custom-module-mage)

Comment: You would need to find some other way rather cacheable="false" on that block because if you set cacheable false on any block it invalidates cache of whole page,  for more you can check devdosc. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-over.html

Comment: Yes, that's why I have added in question **Not cacheable="false"**

Comment: just want to share this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn/9125519#9125519

Comment: @magefms thanks for sharing, but the post is too old, and it is related to Magento 1

Comment: this one as well for M2, https://trellis.co/blog/magento2-fpc-hole-punching/

Comment: @magefms I had read this article, it is telling to disable whole page from Page cache or Flush cache when something is changed. I don't think this article is good read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find out hole punching criteria, I hope this would help others too.

We use hole punching for private contents only, like

- Items in cart on header
- Wishlist count on header
- etc

While we apply Full page cache, we need to use hole punch on private contents to make it call dynamically without cache. To do this we have these types of hole punching

- Ajax based
- Local storage

**Ajax:** 
We already know what is ajax calling, so, if you want the data to load without cache, then call it through ajax.

**Local Storage:**
We can use local storage to call our private data. Good thing is, Magento already stores local storage in it's default functionality. So, we just need to use it anywhere we want.

**Example:**
If you want wishlist count on header then we can call it using `ko templating` like this:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'">
    <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter  -->
    <span class="counter wishlist_count" data-bind="text: wishlist().counter"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: wishlist().counter  -->
    <span class="counter wishlist_count" data-bind="html:'<?php echo __('0 item'); ?>'"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

After this, we just need to call wishlist component like this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "wishlist": {
                        "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

I have tried it by myself, and it is working perfectly along with magento Full Page Cache.

Comment: What's your opinion on using ko templating?  Do you find it works well with caching?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented it, and it is working. The only issue I am facing is that It is not showing wishlist count on page load, it is updating it after few seconds of page load